# how to download zip folder in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have download zip file in tmp folder now i have downloaded zip file but i am not downloaded zip file.
My Code this type=>

## => Download folder

```
def download_folder

    @patient_id = params[:patient_id]
    @photovideos = Photovideo.where('patient_id = ?', User.encrypt(@patient_id))
    @time_filename = Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S").to_s << ".zip"
    tmp_filename = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/"+ @time_filename

    Zip::File.open(tmp_filename, Zip::File::CREATE) do |z|
        @photovideos.each do |photovideo|
            item = User.decrypt(photovideo[:patient_file])
            file = "#{Rails.root}/public/patients/#{@patient_id}/"+ item
            if File.exists?(file)
                t = File.open(file)
                z.add(item, t)
            end
            end
    end
    File.chmod(0777, tmp_filename)
           send_file tmp_filename, :type=>"application/zip", :x_sendfile=>true

    tmp_filename.delete() #To remove the tempfile
    render json: { 'response' => 'Add files.'}

end
```

Comment: AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in DocsnaphomesController#download_folder

Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".

Answer (score 0):

```
def download_folder
        @patient_id = params[:patient_id]
        @photovideos = Photovideo.where('patient_id = ?', User.encrypt(@patient_id))
        @time_filename = Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S").to_s << ".zip"
        tmp_filename = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/"+ @time_filename

        Zip::File.open(tmp_filename, Zip::File::CREATE) do |z|
            @photovideos.each do |photovideo|
                item = User.decrypt(photovideo[:patient_file])
                file = "#{Rails.root}/public/patients/#{@patient_id}/"+ item
                File.chmod(0777, file)
                if File.exists?(file)
                    t = File.open(file)
                    z.add(item, t)
                end
                end
        end
        File.chmod(0777, tmp_filename)
        http_path = "http://"+"#{request.host}"+"/testfixirapi/tmp/"+"#{@time_filename}"
        render json: { 'response' =>  http_path }

    end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function download_patient_folder(patient_id){
    var $url = 'docsnaphomes/download_folder';
    $.post($url, {patient_id: patient_id}, function(data){
        window.location = data.response;
    });
}
```

Comment: working fine for me i have change root path to http path and window.location same browser downloaded file.